# Checking Java code fragments using eclipse AST

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to check for syntactical and logical correctness some Java code fragments using the eclipse abstract syntax tree.

I did some research on how this could be done, I read the documentation, but I haven't found a clear example.

So, I want to check for correctness a set of statements, something like:

```
System.out.println("I'm doing something");
callAMethod(7);
 System.out.println("I'm done");**sdsds**
```

Something like that. You got the point. Here, **sdsds** should be signaled as erroneous.

My question is how can I detect if the Java text is incorrect syntactically or lexically? And how can I get the messages describing the errors?

My code for that is:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
parser.setSource(textToParse.toCharArray());
parser.setResolveBindings(false); 
ASTNode node = (ASTNode) parser.createAST(null); 
 // If MALFORMED bit is 1, then we have an error. The position of MALFORMED 
 being 1, then this should detect the error. **But it doesn't. What's the problem?**
    if (node.getFlags() % 2 == 1) { 
    // error detected
}

if (node instanceof CompilationUnit) {
    // there are severe parsing errors (unrecognized characters for example)
    if (((CompilationUnit) node).getProblems().length != 0) {
        // error detected
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The example you provided as being "incorrect" isn't incorrect syntactically or logically. It is only incorrect *semantically* if in the entire Java application, there is no package "Sy7stem". The *parser* doesn't know that; you have to go beyond parsing to name and type resolution (which you can realistically only do on entire programs. Try a different, one that is clearly broken, say involving the the text [;] which is not valid Java syntax under any circumstance.

Comment: Thanks. You were perfectly right about my example. I edited the question, the example is good now (I think). The code still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the Eclipse parser API, so I don't know how to help you make the check for "bad syntax" work. Just want to make clear that *all* you can expect from the parser is "bad syntax"; you can't get "logical correctness" (whatever that means if it different than 'syntactically valid'). If your need is to do more sophisticated checking than just syntax, this whole approach is incomplete or won't work.  There may be more help from the Eclipse APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the parser kind to K_COMPILATION_UNIT and invoke the parser then you can ask the returned compilation unit for problems.

```
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    IProblem[] problems = cu.getProblems();
    for(IProblem problem : problems) {
        System.out.println("problem: " + problem.getMessage() + problem.getSourceStart());
    }
```

Comment: thanks. It works somehow this way. The thing is that, no matter what text I give to the parser, the first problem is always this one: **Syntax error on token "++", * expected before this token0**. Even though there is no "++" anywhere in the input. What's the reason for this behavior? Thx again, anyway :)